# Confusion on proving the independence of two events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose there are 15 males and 25 females, a total of 40. I am trying to show that the probability of a person being male given that they're female is an independent event. Obviously, the two events can't happen at the same time, which suggests their independence, but I'm a little confused on how to prove this mathematically.

The rule for independent events is that: $P(A \cap B) = P(A)$.

So here's what I did:
$$P(\text{male} \cap \text{female}) = 0$$
$$P(\text{male}) = \frac{15}{40}$$

But then $P(A \cap B) \neq P(A)$, which means it should be dependent when it's not!

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You are conflating disjointness and independence. The intuition is that knowing someone is female gives you a lot of information about whether they are male, so they are very dependent. [See this discussion.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446011/independence-of-disjoint-events)

Comment: So to clarify, does that mean that the two disjoint events of being male and female are actually dependent? My initial intuition of independence is whether or not they can happen at the same time, so I guess that's flawed.

Comment: Indeed. Moreover, "the rule for independent events" is not what you wrote.

Comment: Oops. I meant to say P(A/B), tho the equations will still be the same. Thanks!